# Block every website but one specific one

Tags: networking

I want to set up some laptops for a contest. For that contest, the users should only be allowed to visit one specific website.
Are there good tools on Linux to accomplish that.
Ideally, they should work systemwide, not just for a browser or something similar.
The contestants will otherwise figure out away to bypass it.
Also, it should not involve the router config, since the contest is held in different locations from time to time.
Is there any good option to accomplish that?

I tried squid, but as needed it is a pain to maintain.
Since if run on the same machine the IP Adress of the Proxy changes every time to Network changes...every Proxy Setting has to be changed.

Comment: Check squid. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599122/restrict-squid-access-to-only-one-site

Comment: I tried it, but since i don't have any experience with proxy servers or with squid for that matter it didn't work somehow when i tried it. Do i need to use a seperate machine as proxy Server or a VM or can i run it on the same machine?

Comment: Nevermind...just forgot to toggle Https to :/

Comment: Squid is not really a good answer, if i want it to work on the same machine, while also be able to change the Network in which the machine is from time to time

Comment: You can use a second portable router as proxy/router/gateway between the clients and the main router or something like that, maybe you can block all ip/domains with the hosts file except one site

Answer (score 0):

Any configuration on the laptops is an insufficient measure, because contestants have some control over the laptop and will try to bypass it.

Squid, in combination with a small NAT router, will probably do what you want if the contestants are not able to use another network, f.e. set-up a hotspot on their phone. The NAT-router will normally prevent the need for re-configuration of Squid.

You might also use a router with filters (Cisco, Ubiquity, etc. or even a Raspberry Pi).

But keep the security measures on a different device than the laptops.